# missing 1 required positional argument when calling class function

Tags: python

I'm missing something here. Below is a simplified version of my code. I have a class

```
class CasaDataSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Data=[]

    def FromLines(self, lines, numaddlparamspec):        
        self.BlockIdentifier = lines[0]
        self.SampleIdentifier = lines[1]
```

etc., and in another class

```
class CasaFile:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.Institution = 'Not Specified'        

    def ReadFile(self, Infile):
        lines = CodeThatMakesLines(Infile)
        numaddlparamspec = 2
        CDS = CasaDataSet()
        CDS.FromLines(lines, numaddlparamspec)
```

But when I call

```
CF = CasaFile()
CF.ReadFile('myfile.vms')
```

I get the error "TypeError: FromLines() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numaddlparamspec'". When I Google this, the answer seems to be that they forgot the parentheses after the instance is created (but I don't think that's happening here?). This is on Python 3.4. Sorry if this is a dupe, but I've seemingly tried every permutation of with and without parentheses.

Comment: To tell the truth from what we can read there is nothing wrong. Can you show how CasaDataSet and particularly FromLines are defined?

Comment: Also, please check http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ on the preferred naming conventions for Python.

Comment: What data contains `lines` variable after `lines = CodeThatMakesLines(Infile)`? I try your code replacing this fragment with `lines = ["123", "345"]` and all works fine.

Comment: By the way none of the methods you created, are class methods. Please follow [`PEP8`](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) naming conventions.

Comment: can you possibly include a stack trace not just an exception?

Comment: Pinturic and kvorobiev are right, there is nothing wrong with this code. Something is buggy with WinPython's implementation of this. I tried it on a different machine and the code worked perfectly. This was even after I tried restarting the kernel in Spyder, so something is bugged somewhere.